# What is the boldest version of the font Neuzeit?

Tags: fonts, history

What's the boldest variant of the "Neuzeit?"

Neuzeit Grotesk (or "GroT") is the boldest I've found online, but I just came across a sample in an illustration that was even bolder than that. I need to be able to match it.

Comment: You should add a sample of the illustration and a link to the heaviest variant you've found, else we're just guessing

Answer (score 5):

Normally, "Black" is used to mark the heaviest (boldest) variant of a font. Or, they use a number scheme, usually running from 100 (lightest) to 900 (heaviest).

So, I'd expect Neuzeit Grotesk Black to be the heaviest variant:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/neuzeit-grotesk/t-black/

[image]

The 'grotesk' part of the name simply refers to the stylistic family of sans serif it is from. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotesque_(typeface_classification)

If you can't find a match, it's possible that whoever made the illustration you're talking about manually tweaked the font or added a stroke to it to make it heavier.

There might be giveaway hallmarks of a stroke being added - for example, the sharp point of the M would be either rounded, flattened or extended if a stroke was added depending on the stroke corner settings/mitre limit.

Can't say any more than that without being able to see the illustration or see what the heaviest variant you've found is.

Comment: With some fonts, you get a heavier variant if you use a small size (e.g. 5pt) and you scale it up to obtain large font size.